# HTML/CSS Positioning a logo to always be at the top left, no matter the screen size

Tags: html, css

My question is a little hard to explain!
Basically, I'm designing a website in HTML/CSS, and I need the logo to always be at the top left. On a windows machine, you can resize the browser from any side if I resize from the left hand side, my logo gets cut off.

A good example of what I'm looking for is facebook, however you resize the screen the logo will stay locked in the top left corner.

Am I having a blonde moment here, or is there a specific way of doing it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Does this CSS not do the trick?

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
```

Comment: Or `position:fixed;` if you want it to stay there even when you scroll.

Comment: Beware of position:fixed if you have the misfortune to have to support IE6 though, it doesn't play nicely with it at all. Edit: Well, there are workarounds but it's a massive pain in the nads (like almost everything is with IE6)

Answer (score 5):

```
position:fixed; top:0; left:0;
```